# How to use Beautiful Soup's find() instead of find_all() for better runtime

Tags: python, find, findall, beautifulsoup

I am writing a webscraper using python's bs4.
I am trying to find the **first image** that has a certain attribute 'data-a-dynamic-image'. Thus far I have the code below, and it works. But, I would prefer to **only use `find()` not `find_all`**. This is because I only care about the first item on the page with that attribute. I don't want to use find_all and waste time sifting through the entire webpage.

```
def siftImage(soup):
    try:
        for line in soup.find_all('img'):
            if line is not None:
                if line.has_attr('data-a-dynamic-image'):
                    return line['src']

    except:
        return 'No Image '
```

This second function I made will only return the result that I want, if the first image on the page is the image that I want, otherwise it will return nothing. But, it has the runtime that I am looking for.

```
def siftImageTwo(soup):
    try:
        line = soup.find('img'):
        if line.has_attr('data-a-dynamic-image'):
            return line['src']

    except:
        return 'No Image '
```

I am looking for some way to have the functionality of the top script with the timing of the bottom script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments) there is a way to search by the custom data-* attributes.
You should try this:

```
line = soup.find('img', attrs={'data-a-dynamic-image': True})
```